# centos7 xxx.so lib lib64 rstudio-server

Tags: r, linux, ldd, .so

I'm installed the rstudio-server with rpm in centos7,but cant not start.
Use ldd to seen some xx.so can not found , but that xxx.so already in /usr/lib64.
I was add the path to ldconfig,add path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH,but not useful
So,what can i do to fix this problem,add xxx.so after ldd info.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLKmN.png)

Comment: Hi Christ, can you please tell us which .so files you cannot link? It would allow us to help you without the need of a crystal ball :)

Comment: libssl.so.10
libcrypto.so.10
libpam.so.0
libstdc++.so.6
this .so files i can found in /usr/lib64,but 'ldd' the rserver's result i can just see /usr/lib